# Which Codewarrior version is needed for HCS08 and HCS12X under Windows 10?

Tags: embedded, nxp-microcontroller, codewarrior, 68hc12

I use Codewarrior

```
- V4.7 for HCS12X    
- V6.3 for HCS08
```

in Windows XP.

Moving CW to Windows 10 seems impossible.
It won’t install, and dongle licensing does not work.

I have tried to figure this out on the NXP site, but I find it extremely difficult and confusing.

Which Codewarrior is needed for  HCS12X and HCS08 in 32 and 64 bit Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah it is nearly impossible. I've struggled lots with this problem. There is an unofficial "hack" someone made - won't link it because my browser says the site is unsafe. However, it would seem that hack only works up to Windows 8, not on Windows 10. I have both IDEs (HCS08 and HCS12) running perfectly on a Windows 7 machine, with dongle license.

We managed to get it running so-so on Windows 10 by doing a dirty hard copy of the hacked installation folder to Windows 10. Various mysterious bugs followed though, so not the best idea.

Another option is to run the Windows XP mode emulator from Microsoft, but it is no longer supported for Windows 10.

So ultimately there are two options left if you are stuck with Windows 10:

- Move development to the worst IDE ever released, Codewarrior for Eclipse. Please note that the future of this IDE is uncertain after the NXP merger. They might decide to put their money on their other trash IDE, LPCxpresso.
- Port your project to another compiler or MCU.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to install it in a VMWare or virtualBox container using Windows 7 as OS.
This makes it possible, that your installation will work even in some years.

I'm using such a container (with WinXP) for an old Visual Basic 6 installation and HEW-IDE.

You should use at least Win7, to avoid the network problems with WinXP (SMB1 can't be connected anymore).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Codewarrior Classic 6.3 community project](https://www.cvorg.ece.udel.edu/2021/03/24/how-to-install-codewarrior-6-3-classic-in-windows-10-or-7-x64/) for RS08, S08, ColdFire V1 for Windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1, and 10. Basically, the installer is repacked will all service packs and patches for USBDM and PEMicro tools.

If you have an obsolete programming tool you will need to use CW 6.3 on XP. Also, if you have these specific family of parts S08: RN, RNA, PA, PT, Kinetis (including Tower), ColdFire V2 you must use the bloated eclipse version [CodeWarrior 11](https://www.nxp.com/design/software/development-software/codewarrior-development-tools/codewarrior-legacy/codewarrior-development-suite-special:CW-SUITE-SPECIAL?tab=Design_Tools_Tab)

For S12 or S12X CodeWarrior Classic 5.2 for Windows 7 - Windows 10
But when they released 5.2 they removed most of the older derivatives from it, but you can add them back using this procedure [CodeWarrior 5.2](https://community.nxp.com/t5/Classic-Legacy-CodeWarrior/How-to-Add-missing-derivatives-to-CodeWarrior-Classic-HCS12-X-5/m-p/585450)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)